# Google Chrome Web Inspector taking up the full screen

Tags: google-chrome

I'm not sure how I did it, but when I right click on the page and choose Inspect Element in Google Chrome, it's taking up the entire page.  I think it's supposed to be a split screen like Firebug.

Q: How do I split the Web Inspector page?

Comment: Oh.  It's dock to main window in the bottom left-hand corner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you drag the window down to resize, split it into its own window, or maybe it already is in its oown window?  There is an option to dock it in the page.

Answer (score 3):

You need to click on the icon "Dock to main window" on the right top corner.

Answer (score 1):

This is really annoying. The bar which allows you to minimize or maximize or window-ize is not there at all. This is the only program that has ever done this to me on mac.

Comment: Still does it on a PC 6th April 2018

really is an annoying bug that seems to happen randomly for no apparent reason